# Ergonomic 4000 - Remap Zoom slider to scroll

Tags: windows-10

I know this was a well documented question, but all guides are out of date. I did get this working last year on Windows 7, but now I'm on Windows 10 and none of the answers seem to apply. I'm on Version 13.0.0.0. and have tried placing  in ALL & ENG  and all that happens is I have to reinstall the Keyboard Centre. Also, is it possible to add another another program to the list?

Comment: IIRC I had to edit some XML files in `%ProgramFiles%` last time. I no longer customize so I don't know whether that's still applicable, sorry.

Comment: No problem, I seem to have somehow got it working. I pasted the C319 Type="6" Activator="ScrollUp", C320 Type="6" Activator="ScrollDown" commands into ALL and restarted IType.exe and it seems to have taken. I was sure I did the same thing an hour ago, but clearly I didn't. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have somehow got it working. I pasted the usual

```
C319 Type="6" Activator="ScrollUp" & 
C320 Type="6" Activator="ScrollDown"
```

commands into ALL and restarted IType.exe and it seems to have taken. I could swear I did this an hour ago and it never worked.

Comment: I just got this working on Windows 11 with [Windows Mouse and Keyboard Center app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2). The `commands.xml` is broken up by language apparently, and I got an error dialog if I tried to put these in both `<ENG>...StandardSupport` and `<ALL> ... StandardSupport`. But just ENG does work.